# How to add the value of the field of the current record of the subordinate form to the field of the parent form?

Tags: ms-access, vba

How to add the value of the field of the current record of the subordinate form to the field of the parent form?

Form structure:
   - frm_00_00_MainForm;
   - - frm_reg_GroupsStud_Stud_tbl;
   - - - reg_GroupsStud_Stud;

reg_GroupsStud_Stud:

```
SELECT tbl_03_GroupsStud.*, tbl_02_Students.NameStud
FROM tbl_03_GroupsStud INNER JOIN tbl_02_Students ON tbl_03_GroupsStud.id_stud = tbl_02_Students.id_stud;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common abstract named way of accessing a control on a subform is (when the code is placed in the main form):

```
Me.subFormControlName.Form.ControlName.Value
```

Where `Me` references the current form you are in, `subFormControlName` is the name of the **control** containing the sub form, `Form` references any form in there (it's name doesn't matter), `ControlName` references a control on the sub form and `Value` reads the controls value.